# No value on array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem when I want to display a value after a `foreach` loop, it does'nt want take the value of `$product_option_value_data` in `product_option_value`

Thank you for your help.

```
foreach ($product_option_value as $products_option_value) {
    $product_option_value_data[] = [
        'products_option_value_id' => $products_option_value['products_option_value_id'],
        'option_value_id'          => $products_option_value['option_value_id'],
        'name'                     => $products_option_value['name'],
        'image'                    => $products_option_value['image'],
        'quantity'                 => $products_option_value['quantity'],
        'subtract'                 => $products_option_value['subtract'],
        'price'                    => $products_option_value['price'],
        'price_prefix'             => $products_option_value['price_prefix'],
        'weight'                   => $products_option_value['weight'],
        'weight_prefix'            => $products_option_value['weight_prefix']
    ];
}
```

Result

```
var_dump($product_option_value_data);

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'products_option_value_id' => string '91' (length=2)
      'option_value_id' => string '180' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'M' (length=1)
      'image' => null
      'quantity' => string '100' (length=3)
      'subtract' => string '0' (length=1)
      'price' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
      'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'weight' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      'weight_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
```

Step 2

```
$product_option_data[] = [
    'products_option_id'    => $product_option['products_option_id'],
    'products_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
    'option_id'            => $product_option['option_id'],
    'name'                 => $product_option['name'],
    'type'                 => $product_option['type'],
    'value'                => $product_option['value'],
    'required'             => $product_option['required']
];
```

Result

```
var_dump($product_option_data);

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '106' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null
```

Problem here

```
var_dump($product_option_data['products_option_value']);
Classes/Shop/ProductsAttributesShop.php:188:null
```

Comment: `var_dump($product_option_data[0]['products_option_value']);`
In last var_dump `$product_option_data` is still 2 dimensional array

Comment: @bato3 ok for one value, but I need all the value of the loop and I haven't in 'products_option_value' => $product_option_value_data

Comment: em... `foreach($product_option_data AS $one) var_dump($one)`?

Comment: @bato3, work with loop and change $product_option_data by $product_option_data[0] and I have the elements. Tk

Comment: you post same problem with several question? lol